# Category tree is not showing in manage categories page?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree

I have installed magento in my server.

I want to add categories but its not showing the categories as category tree.

If I click add root category or add subcategory, nothing is working in that page.

Category tree is appearing once i refresh the page and its disappearing once the page got loaded.

**error in console**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateContent is not defined at
>   _renderNewTree (VM309:748) at reRenderTree (VM309:720) at VM309:860 at Ext.util.Event.fire (ext-tree.js:29) at _a (ext-tree.js:33) at
>   ext-tree.js:33

Anyone can help?

Comment: any js error in console ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: updateContent is not defined
    at _renderNewTree (VM309:748)
    at reRenderTree (VM309:720)
    at VM309:860
    at Ext.util.Event.fire (ext-tree.js:29)
    at _a (ext-tree.js:33)
    at ext-tree.js:33

Comment: give proper permission to magento folders like js and skin folder

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is some error in your JS. Download a fresh Magento from https://magento.com/tech-resources/download and compare your js/extjs/ext-tree.js with it.